# how to make the slider value one decimal place?

Tags: swift, uislider

Now, the value of the slider shows seven decimal places. I'd like to make it one decimal place when I'm controlling.

like. 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc...

```
  @IBAction func slider(_ sender: Any) {
        sliderlabel.text = String(UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "playSpeed"))
        UserDefaults.standard.set(slider.value, forKey:"playSpeed")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sliderlabel.text = String(UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "playSpeed"))
        slider.setValue(UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey:"playSpeed"), animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want slider value to print upto 2 decimal point:

```
 @IBAction func heightSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider)
    {
        let sliderValue = sender.value
        print(String(format: "%.2f", sliderValue))
    }
```

if you want upto 1 decimal point: format: "%.1f"

Answer (score 3):

Format your string using :

```
let playSpeed =  UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "playSpeed")!
let string = String(format: "%.1f", playSpeed)
sliderlabel.text = string
```

Comment: No. Use a NumberFormatter for user-facing text.